# Vuex - access state in modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

So I'm lost...
I have a Vuex. And I have a module `common` in file `common.js`:

```
const initState = {
  fruits: []
}
export default {
  state: initState,
  mutations: {
    SET_FRUITS(state, fruits) {
      console.log(fruits);
      state.fruits = fruits;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async getFruits({ commit }) {
      const fruits =[
        {
          text: 'Apple',
          value: {id: 1, val: 'apple'},
        },
        {
          text: 'Banana',
          value: {id: 2, val: 'banana'},
        },
        {
          text: 'Pear',
          value: {id: 3, val: 'pear'},
        },
        {
          text: 'Plum',
          value: {id: 4, val: 'plum'},
        }
      ];

      commit('SET_FRUITS', fruits);
    }
  }
}
```

my `store` in `index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import common from './modules/common';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    common,
  }
})
```

I try to access state.fruits in App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ this.$store.state.fruits }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('getFruits');
    console.log(this.$store.state.fruits);
  },
}
</script>
```

`console.log` from mutations returns array of fruits. It works. It's cool.
`console.log` from `mounted()` in App.vue returns undefined. It's not cool.

Why? What do I miss?

Comment: Did you try `this.$store.state.comon.fruits` ?

Comment: Well i wasn't so sure about it that's why it was a one liner question. But what brings the question lies in this [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#modules)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example. Also double check your vuex store configuration/registration, and don't forget to use `dispatch`

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    fruits: []
  },
  actions: {
    getFruits({
      commit
    }) {
      const fruits = [{
          text: 'Apple',
          value: {
            id: 1,
            val: 'apple'
          },
        },
        {
          text: 'Banana',
          value: {
            id: 2,
            val: 'banana'
          },
        },
        {
          text: 'Pear',
          value: {
            id: 3,
            val: 'pear'
          },
        },
        {
          text: 'Plum',
          value: {
            id: 4,
            val: 'plum'
          },
        }
      ];

      console.log(fruits)

      commit('SET_FRUITS', fruits);
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_FRUITS(state, fruits) {
      state.fruits = fruits;
    }
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  computed: {
    fruits() {
      return this.$store.state.fruits;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getFruits')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.5.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div v-for='(fruit, i) in fruits' :key="i">
    {{fruit}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems you have changed my approach. I asked about access to state in module, and the code I submitted is very simplified example of an issue. Eldar's answer is the answer I needed.

Your solutions is fine, of course, but it does not match my question :)